# How to initialize multiple structures at an arbitrary point of an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization

I have a structure in C defined by

```
struct problem_spec_point {
        int point_no;
        double x;
        double y;
        int bc;
};
```

I have an array of these structures of length 6, with the first four structures defined explicitly on initialization.

```
static struct point points[6] =
    {
        {0, 1, 2, 5},
        {0, 1, 2, 6},
        {0, 1, 2, 7},
        {0, 1, 2, 8},
    };
```

I can add the 5th and 6th structures later:
`points[4] = (struct point) {0,1,2,12}; points[5] = (struct point) {3,3,3,3};` 
But suppose that I wanted to add these two (or multiple) consecutive structures, all at once.
Something like

`points[4] = {(struct point) {0,1,2,12}, (struct point) {3,3,3,3},};` 
Is there any such way to do this?

Obviously I tried the syntax listed above.

For context, in reality my code has an array of length 3n+6. I have a for-loop assigning the first 3n structures their values, but the last 6 have a different, odd pattern.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3n; i++)
{
 point[i] = stuff;
}

//odd points here at end of array
```

I could switch the order and do some indexing changes:

```
static struct point points[3n+6] = 
{
  last points first
}

for(int i = 6; i < 3n+6, i++
{
  point[i]=stuff;
}
```

But I don't want to. I am not super familiar with C, and I am curious.

This is my first post, so please forgive me if I did not follow the normal format.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is likely just to type it out in plain, readable code:

```
points[4] = (struct point) {0,1,2,12};
points[5] = (struct point) {3,3,3,3};
```

Alternatively for big intervals with the same value etc, use `memcpy`. Perhaps something along the lines of this:

```c
#include <string.h>

void add_points (struct point* points, const struct point* val, size_t from, size_t to)
{
  for(size_t i=from; i<=to; i++)
  {
    memcpy(&points[i], val, sizeof(struct points));
  }
}


// usage example: assign {3,3,3,3} from index 4 to index 5

add_points(points, &(struct point){3,3,3,3}, 4, 5);
```

(This code can be optimized slightly by using `restrict` pointers.)

Answer (score 0):

Lundin rightly told that you can use `memcpy`. He didn't explicitly mention that you can reformulate your attempt for different values

```
points[4] = {(struct point) {0,1,2,12}, (struct point) {3,3,3,3},};
```

with `memcpy` like

```
    memcpy(points+4, (struct point []){ {0,1,2,12}, {3,3,3,3} },
              sizeof (struct point [2]));
```

Comment: This is IMO far less clear than just assigning to the array items directly, one at a time.

Comment: You are certainly right for two or a few more array items, less certainly for many consecutive items.

Comment: memcpy can only be clearer that direct assignment if the array data is declared separately (as `const`), instead of as one big ugly compound literal.